# How can I support source file subdirectories (with common file names) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a (C++) project that I originally developed under Linux using make to build it. I would like to also have it run in Windows and am using Visual Studio 2005 to build it. The problem I'm running into is that Visual Studio places all objects into the same output directory. This doesn't work for me because I have source files with the same name in different sub-directories. This means that the last object (with the common name) overwrites all previous ones and thus I get link errors for the "missing" code.

Setting the output directory (even using the Visual Studio variables like $(InputDir)) at the project level doesn't work because Visual Studio passes all of the source files to cl.exe at once (i.e. $(InputDir) is evaluated once rather than for each input file). It appears that this problem can be solved by manually setting the output directory for each file (at a minimum, for the affected files), but this is less than optimal and error-prone.

Is there a better way to solve this problem? I would even appreciate it even if someone is able to suggest a way to get Visual Studio to compile files one-at-a-time so that setting the output directory at the project level would have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using different project for each directory or so. Otherwise, using the exactly same filename within a certain project might seem a bit strange. (Sort of a hierarchy within the project structure; something I've never seen before anyway.)